# Interpretting the output of dumpsys telephony.registry

Tags: adb, cellular-radio

So when I run the command

```
dumpsys telephony.registry | grep -i signalstrength
```

I get the following output:

```
mSignalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -93 -12 300 2147483647 gsm|lte
```

I'm assuming the -93 is the dB value but I'm not sure. And for the other values I have no idea. I tried searching for a table to map each value but I couldn't find anything. I would really appreciate it if someone can let me know what each value means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the sources, it looks like it's printing out the contents of the `SignalStrength` object:

> ```
> private SignalStrength mSignalStrength = new SignalStrength();
>
> ...
>
>         pw.println("last known state:");
>         ...
>         pw.println("  mSignalStrength=" + mSignalStrength);
>         ...
> ```

This object is described in detail on the Android Developers reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html).  The string representation of the SignalStrength class is defined [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/SignalStrength.java) (search for "toString" function):

> ```
> public String toString() {
>     return ("SignalStrength:"
>             + " " + mGsmSignalStrength
>             + " " + mGsmBitErrorRate
>             + " " + mCdmaDbm
>             + " " + mCdmaEcio
>             + " " + mEvdoDbm
>             + " " + mEvdoEcio
>             + " " + mEvdoSnr
>             + " " + mLteSignalStrength
>             + " " + mLteRsrp
>             + " " + mLteRsrq
>             + " " + mLteRssnr
>             + " " + mLteCqi
>             + " " + (isGsm ? "gsm|lte" : "cdma"));
> }
> ```

This basically tells you the columns in the dumpsys output.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the code that produces this output in [SignalStrength.java in the Android framework](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/SignalStrength.java#L884). Even if you don't know Java, it's pretty easy to see which raw value is which.

If there are any values you don't understand (the names are pretty concise and only make sense if you're familiar with phone standards), you can read the inline documentation elsewhere in the same file.